# Adjust monitor settings to compensate for vision problems

Tags: monitor

Is there any software that allows to "blur" or sharpen what's on your monitor to compensate for vision problem in Ubuntu?

I sometimes forget my glasses (I leave them at work, or forget them at home).
and it might be useful to somehow adjust what's on your monitor to see clearly.

Comment: Did you know about this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility ? `orca`

Comment: @Rinzwind no I didn't know about the Accessibility tools, but none of them actually seems to solve my issue.. orca is a screen reader, which is not what I want.. thanks for the advice anyway